# How to install libpng using yum?

Tags: centos, libpng

how do I install libpng using yum on centos?

I tried `yum install libpng` but that does not work

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I've tested it and it works on my machine running CentOS 7 so that the right way to install it. Can you give us the output of `yum install libpng` and `yum provides libpng`?

Comment: Try `sudo yum install libpng-devel`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this command:

```
yum install libpng-devel
```